# React passing down a function that modifies a third component

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to create a component per function in my app, but I am facing the following issue.
I have the component DisplayAllData that sends the data and an actionable button to DisplayDataWithButton, the issue is that when someone clicks on the Button send in the props, the function modifies the state of the parent component, which is also sent as a parameter to FullScreenDialog, and that throws a Warning: Cannot update a component while rendering a different component.
I designed the components in this particular way because:

1. DisplayAllData is the only function that has the data to render and the actionable button. (Model)
2. DisplayDataWithButton only renders the data and displays the actionable components for that particular data, in this case a button that opens a Dialog in screen. (Viewer)

You can find a running example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8oyef

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import DisplayDataWithButton from "./DisplayDataWithButton";
import FullScreenDialog from "./fullscreendialog";

export default function App(props) {
  const [openFullScreen, setopenFullScreen] = React.useState(false);
  var items = ["John", "Melinda"];
  var dataDisplayFunction = (data) => {
    return data.map((item) => {
      return [
        item,
        <Button
          color="success"
          size="small"
          className="px-2"
          variant="contained"
          onClick={setopenFullScreen()}
        >
          Show Dialog
        </Button>
      ];
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DisplayDataWithButton
        shapeDataFunction={dataDisplayFunction}
        data={items}
      />
      <FullScreenDialog open={openFullScreen} />
    </>
  );
}
```

DisplayDataWithButton.js

```
export default function DisplayDataWithButton(props) {
  return props.shapeDataFunction(props.data);
}
```

I suspect that there is another way to implement this model, any suggestion, or ideas on how to fix this one.

Thanks

Comment: If you post a minimum working example with the error I will help you. The code you have provided is incomplete

Comment: @AlexMckay thanks for the offer, I just created a demo, check the console of https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8oyef

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: @AlexMckay thank you very much. That did the trick. Could you explain why the toggle option works better here:  onClick={() => setopenFullScreen((prev) => !prev)}

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you are asking. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for clarification on passing functions to access previous state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things: "I have been trying to create a component per function in my app". Forget that - the pattern you have opted for here is called render props but I don't see how it is necessary. Keep it simple. If a big component is simpler to understand than a small component I always opt for the bigger component. Splitting your components will not magically make them easier to understand.

All of the warnings have been dealt with. Most of them were simple mistakes, for example: `onClick={setopenFullScreen()}` should be `onClick={setopenFullScreen}`. You can compare [your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8oyef?file=/fullscreendialog.js) with [my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-53q1r?file=/fullscreendialog.js) for all of the changes.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import FullScreenDialog from "./fullscreendialog";

export default function App() {
  const [openFullScreen, setopenFullScreen] = React.useState(false);
  const items = ["John", "Melinda"];
  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item) => [
        item,
        <Button
          key={item}
          color="primary"
          size="small"
          className="px-2"
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => setopenFullScreen((prev) => !prev)}
        >
          Show Dialog
        </Button>
      ])}
      <FullScreenDialog open={openFullScreen} />
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  appBar: {
    position: "relative"
  },
  title: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    flex: 1
  }
}));

const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});

export default function FullScreenDialog(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        fullScreen
        open={props.open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
      >
        <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              edge="start"
              color="inherit"
              onClick={handleClose}
              aria-label="close"
            >
              <CloseIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
              Sound
            </Typography>
            <Button autoFocus color="inherit" onClick={handleClose}>
              save
            </Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <List>
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemText primary="Phone ringtone" secondary="Titania" />
          </ListItem>
          <Divider />
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemText
              primary="Default notification ringtone"
              secondary="Tethys"
            />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```